# Get version_name from the version_code of an android package?

Tags: javascript, android, google-play

Is there any way to get the version_name based on the version_code of an android package?

For example: 
'com.nianticlabs.pokemongo'
version_code: 2017121800
  => version_name: 0.87.5

all I want is something like:

```
function getVersionName(version_code) {
   // do smt with version_code
   return version_name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

But I don't think you can get one depending on the other, those are two separate things: only a string and an int

In native java you have:

```
public static int getVersionCode(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return pInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}

public static String getVersionName(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return pInfo.versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

you could look for the equivalent in your javascript google API

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get version name:

```
 private String getVersionName() {

            versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            return versionName;
        }
```

Comment: it's a nice tip !

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in general. Every app is completely free to choose it's own version name (user readable string) and version code scheme. Many apps will have two APKs which have different version codes with exactly the same version name. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html).